# Initialize Javascript Select2 controller using HTML5 data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-select2

I'm trying to manage [select2 library](https://select2.github.io/) in order to augment the capabilities of natives select html controls.

According to the official documentation (very compressed) it says that  for using select2 you only need to download they CSS and JavaScript files and that is (and also, implicitly assumed, that you need jQuery).

So, there is a way of initializing select using [HTML5 data attributes](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data-attributes), but I am not getting it; I'm trying to follow their example. Perhaps I am missing some important note here.

Here is the HTML I am trying to do

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Select2</h1>
  <div>
      <select multiple id="a_select" data-tags="true" data-placeholder="Select an option" data-allow-clear="true" style="width:100%">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
      </select>
  </div> 

  </body>

</html>
```

Also a link to plunker, to have a live example ready to go. https://plnkr.co/edit/Xk101K3sowAYQwbRCFez?p=preview

PS: I can achieve the desired result thought JavaScript, but is quite annoying to don't know what is not working when i just followed the example on the official site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not initializing Select2 anywhere... `data-*` attributes let you override default configuration, but you still need to kick off the plugin:

```
<script>$('select').select2();</script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/RPObSPVl8jlZgtedsK38?p=preview

Comment: Okey, i see, that's works... but the documentation doesn't specificy that you have to use javascript.

Comment: [Yes it does](https://select2.github.io/). Not to mention, [every single example](https://select2.github.io/examples.html).

Comment: sorry Adnré, but it doesn't say that explicitty right in the example, therebefore is implicit information you can say.... you will have to excuse me, but working with other frameworks you discover that is actually possible to archive the desired effects thought html5 data attributes as with javascript . For example: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. In now a days, i guess, it won't harm anyone to complete the documentation. This is off topic, but again, i have a point. Take it or not, is up to you.

Comment: I don't see your point. In both your original question and now in your bootstrap "counter" example there are **explicit** instructions that were incredibly easy to find. Don't chalk up inability to read all pertinent information as "incomplete documentation" just because it's not repeated verbatim for every code snippet or example you may happen to come across...

Comment: it was a suggestion andré, the docs aims to be straigh foward but in the sake of simplicity they are missing points. For example, they forgot to mention that you must include jquery in order to start, you could argue  that is trivial, but now a days there are some libraries (at least ANgular js) that comes with lite version of jquery if you doens't include. I mean, this is  how a work, if you claim to be straight foward you should be absollutely clear, context is important. Is my point of view. We can chat about this in another topic glady! anyway, thanks for the help!